# Why Material-UI date overlaps value with placeholder and complains about controlled input?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-moon-zc77k?file=/src/DateOnly.js).

I want to create a `DateOnly` component that I can use with ease throughout my projects.

And Material-UI complains that:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

And here's how it shows the selected date:

[image]

I know that controlled input means that you bind both `value={value}` and `onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue);}`.

And here's my return value:

```
return (
    <div>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        error={isValid() ? false : true}
        id={id}
        label={placeholder}
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={currentValue}
        onChange={(date) => {
          setCurrentValue(date);
        }}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "Change " + placeholder
        }}
        fullWidth
      />
    </div>
  );
```

But I don't know why this date field fails to recognize that.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `value={currentValue || null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code:

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(
  new Date(value) || new Date()
);
```

To:

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(
  value ? new Date(value) : new Date()
);
```

`new Date(undefined)` is an invalid date (because your component doesn't initialize `value` prop). When you pass invalid date value to the picker component, it can't register so it thinks you're using uncontrolled mode and unexpected result happens.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]